# Разбор записи SQL

Tags: php, mysql

У меня такой вопрос, если у нас есть запись в SQL, например "14,15,16,17", можно ли эти значения получить в массив php array1 и как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array=explode(', ', "14, 15, 16, 17");
print_r($array);
```